# Bind New Column To GridView C# **UPDATED**

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, arraylist

Ok updating this because i've gotten a little further this afternoon..

I've merged my code together how ever it's still not correct, i've added a picture to give you guys a proper view of what im trying to do and what it looks like.

The results are going to a new row?? i think i need to add a match so if the IP addresses from my array list and the ones in the current Gridview match then line them up correctly in the same row.

Here is my Code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PullData();
        }
        public void PullData()
        {            
            string SQLRET = "SELECT RX_ID, ShopID, Primary_IP, ServiceType, Hardware FROM RouterHealthCheck";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLRET, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Results", typeof(string));
            da.Fill(dt);


            ArrayList IPAddresses = new ArrayList(GetList());

            List<string> Results = new List<string>();

            foreach (string IPAddress in IPAddresses)
            {
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(IPAddress);

                if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    Results.Add(string.Format("Success"));
                }
                else
                {
                    Results.Add(string.Format("Offline"));
                }
            }
            foreach (string results in Results)
            {                
                dt.Rows.Add(results);
            }            

            if (dt.Columns.Count > 0)
            {

                GridViewRouters.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewRouters.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {                
                DataTable dts = new DataTable();
                GridViewRouters.DataSource = dts;
                GridViewRouters.DataBind();
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        public ArrayList GetList()
        {
            ArrayList GetList = new ArrayList();

            string GETIP = "SELECT Primary_IP FROM RouterHealthCheck";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

                conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GETIP, conn))
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    a.Fill(ds);
                    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            GetList.Add(dr["Primary_IP"].ToString());
                        }                        
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            return GetList;
        }                                       
      }
```

[image: whatitlookslike]

Comment: what is the sequence of your method calls ? I think you should combine all three functions into one and prepare the final DataTable before assigning it as the DataSource of your GridView

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PullData();
            GetList();
        }

Comment: obviously when i call the PingIT the grid view gets a new data source and hides the data already there

Comment: For one thing you can add the results field to select list as a hard coded value - that will make the code a little easier to read: `Select 'Offline' as Results, RX_ID, Shop_id....`  but then you need to find and update the appropriate row based on some criteria. Or you can place the ping data into a second datatable and [Merge the tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i tried merging before and i had allot of trouble with trying to add the array list to the current data table. can you provide me with a example code?

Comment: Why are you fetching the IP list again in GetList() method while you have already got that column in PullData() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the SQL query in your code, I think you can have this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PullData();
        }
        public void PullData()
        {            
            string SQLRET = "SELECT RX_ID, ShopID, Primary_IP, ServiceType, Hardware FROM RouterHealthCheck";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLRET, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("Results", typeof(string));

//iterate the rows and ping each IP. Additionaly you can also code to ignore repeating IP
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {                            
Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(dr["Primary_IP"].ToString());

                if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    dr["Results"] = string.Format("Success");
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["Results"] = string.Format("Offline");
                }
                        } 

GridViewRouters.DataSource = dt;
                GridViewRouters.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Solved thanks i had to alter the Foreach statment to: foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Columns[0].Table.Rows) but it looks like it's all working awsome !!